# How to prevent word wrap using CSS for a specific group of words on the DOM?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a series of input labels:

```html
    <label>
      <abbr>*</abbr>
      Label Text Here
    </label>
```

On browser resize some labels wrap like this:
`* 
Label
Text Here`

Ideally text should not break between the asterisk and the first word-- like so:

`* Label
Text Here`

I can't use `&nbsp;`/change the HTML because my inputs and labels are automatically generated and I don't have control over the HTML output. I'm looking for pure CSS solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am seeing your html code. If you try to give a width to the label i think you resolve it. Like `width: 30%;` or something like that.

Comment: Hmm, this caused the wrap to occur sooner when shrinking the browser width @lisarko8077 What I'm
 looking for is a way to not wrap after the asterisk

Comment: How about adding `display: flex` to `label`?

Comment: Also if you are using `<abbr>*</abbr>` you are using it wrong since an asterisk in not an abbreviation for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add  `white-space: nowrap;` to `label`

This will not wrap your text on to next line.

```css
label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label>
      <abbr>*</abbr>
      Label Text Here
    </label>
```

Comment: To clarify I want the label to wrap I just want to avoid wrapping between the * and the first word of the label.